# Enumerações podem conter métodos?

Tags: java, enums

Não sei se o termo é esse, "métodos abstratos em um `enum`".

Minha dúvida surgiu após ver [essa implementação no *code review*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/73369/). Até então eu nunca tinha visto esse tipo de coisa em nenhum tutorial ou artigo referente a `enum` em Java e achei sensacional. Segue um trecho:

```
public enum Choices {
   ROCK("rock") {
       @Override
       public List<Choices> getWinsAgainst() {
          if (winsAgainst.isEmpty()) {
              winsAgainst.add(SCISSORS);
              winsAgainst.add(LIZARD);
          }
          return winsAgainst;
       }
   }

   // restante do código
}
```

1. Uma enumeração pode ter um método implementado dentro dela?
2. Como funciona o controle de acesso a esses métodos?
3. Quando utilizar essa prática? Implementar diretamente no `enum` ao
   invés de ter uma classe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em Java, uma enumeração nada mas é que uma classe quer herda [implicitamente] de `Enum`. O número de instâncias da mesma é fixo, e ela pode ou não ser abstrata - o importante é que **todos** os seus elementos sejam concretos. Ou seja, se ela possui métodos abstratos, então todo elemento precisa ter um corpo [que implemente esses métodos]. Caso contrário, eles podem ter ou não.

- Uma enumeração pode ter tudo o que uma classe tem, inclusive campos e métodos.

  ```
  public enum Planet {
      MERCURY (3.303e+23, 2.4397e6),
      VENUS   (4.869e+24, 6.0518e6),
      EARTH   (5.976e+24, 6.37814e6),
      MARS    (6.421e+23, 3.3972e6),
      JUPITER (1.9e+27,   7.1492e7),
      SATURN  (5.688e+26, 6.0268e7),
      URANUS  (8.686e+25, 2.5559e7),
      NEPTUNE (1.024e+26, 2.4746e7);

      private final double mass;   // in kilograms
      private final double radius; // in meters
      Planet(double mass, double radius) {
          this.mass = mass;
          this.radius = radius;
      }
      private double mass() { return mass; }
      private double radius() { return radius; }

      // universal gravitational constant  (m3 kg-1 s-2)
      public static final double G = 6.67300E-11;

      double surfaceGravity() {
          return G * mass / (radius * radius);
      }
      double surfaceWeight(double otherMass) {
          return otherMass * surfaceGravity();
      }
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          if (args.length != 1) {
              System.err.println("Usage: java Planet <earth_weight>");
              System.exit(-1);
          }
          double earthWeight = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
          double mass = earthWeight/EARTH.surfaceGravity();
          for (Planet p : Planet.values())
             System.out.printf("Your weight on %s is %f%n",
                               p, p.surfaceWeight(mass));
      }
  }
  ```

  <sup>[Fonte](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)</sup>.

  O controle de acesso a esses métodos é o mesmo que o de qualquer classe (`public`, `private`, `protected`...). Exceto pelo construtor, que precisa ser "padrão" - i.e. sem nenhum modificador - ou privado, uma vez que você não pode chamá-lo diretamente para criar novas instâncias da `enum`.
- Uma enumeração pode ter métodos abstratos na sua definição (i.e. a parte "normal" do código); entretanto, cada um dos seus elementos precisa implementar esses métodos, pois cada um deles é uma classe concreta e `final`:

  ```
  public enum Choices {
     ROCK("rock") {
         public List<Choices> getWinsAgainst() { ... }
     },
     PAPER("paper") { ... },       // Precisa implementar getWinsAgainst
     SCISSORS("scissors") { ... }; // Precisa implementar getWinsAgainst
     SPOCK("Spock") { ... },       // Precisa implementar getWinsAgainst
     LIZARD("lizard") { ... },     // Precisa implementar getWinsAgainst

     private String nome;
     Choices(String nome) {
         this.nome = nome;
     }

     public abstract List<Choices> getWinsAgainst(); // todos os elementos
                                                     // precisam implementar
  }
  ```
- No mais, toda enumeração herda implicitamente de `Enum` (i.e. não pode herdar de outra classe qualquer, mas pode implementar interfaces normalmente). Possui se não me engano um tipo genérico igual ao próprio tipo, ex.: `enum X extends Enum<X>`, também implicitamente estabelecido. Cada elemento que tenha corpo possui sua própria classe, e ele é o único objeto da mesma (i.e. *singleton*). Não se pode herdar da classe desses elementos (i.e. são `final`), nem da própria `enum`. Também não se pode criar novas instâncias da `enum` (i.e. é *de facto* abstrata - embora elementos sem corpo sejam instâncias dela).

Sobre quando utilizar, eu diria que somente nos casos em que o número de instâncias é finito, conhecido em tempo de compilação, e improvável de mudar no futuro. Eu tenho dificuldade de pensar em exemplos, mas pense em conjuntos "naturais" como os pontos cardeais (norte, sul, leste, oeste) ou convenções que dificilmente serão substituídas no futuro, como os dias da semana (domingo, segunda, terça, quarta, quinta, sexta, sábado). Pessoalmente, vejo pouca utilidade nas `enum`s (exceto pela possibilidade de usá-la num `switch`, que não é muito OO de qualquer forma), mas alguém com mais experiência prática em Java pode conhecer mais casos de uso.