# Como criar métodos em um enum?

Tags: c#, .net, método, enums

Tenho uma aplicação em Java e estou portando ela para C#. Tenho uma dúvida em relação ao `enum` que parece trabalhar diferente do Java. Depois de ter feito uma pergunta aqui no site ([Enumerações podem conter métodos abstratos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43756/4808)), sempre que possível opto por centralizar métodos e propriedades em um `enum`. Pois bem, em Java meu código está assim:

```java
enum BBcodes {

   BOLD("b"),
   ITALIC("i"),
   //...
   UNDERLINE("u");

   private final String code;
   public BBcodes(String code){
      this.code = code;
   }

   public string wrap(String contents){
      return MessageFormat.format("[{0}]{1}[/{0}]", this.code, contents);
   }
}
```

No qual posso chamá-lo assim:

```
String bbcode = BBcodes.BOLD.wrap("StackOverflow"); //[b]StackOverflow[/b]
```

Vi [nessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588384/how-to-define-an-enum-with-string-value) que não posso criar um `enum` que guarda valores do tipo `string`. Não sei se é a melhor forma de resolver, mas criei uma classe para isso:

```csharp
public class BBcodes
{
   public static readonly string BOLD = "b";
   public static readonly string ITALIC = "i";
   //...

   public static string Wrap(string code, string contents)
   {
      return string.Format("[{0}]{1}[/{0}]", code, contents);
    }
}
```

No qual chamo assim:

```
string bbcode = BBcodes.Wrap(BBcodes.BOLD, "StackOverflow"); //[b]StackOverflow[/b]
```

Não é um problema fazer dessa forma, tendo que passar o respectivo valor do BBCode como argumento para o método `Wrap`. É algo que dá pra acostumar. :)

Mas se possível, eu gostaria de fazer algo o mais próximo possível do Java,  criando tudo (os valores e métodos) no próprio `enum`. Como eu poderia fazer isto em C#? É possível?

Comment: Adoro esse tipo de pergunta, certamente será útil para algum usuário no futuro.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Em C# os tipos de enumerações são tratados de forma diferente dos outros tipos. [Não é um classe como é no Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110142/101). De fato você achou uma das poucas coisas que claramente o C# é pior que o Java e não é possível colocar métodos dentro das enumerações. É bom salientar que uma enumeração em C# é um tipo por valor e normalmente é equivalente a um inteiro (pode especificar o tipo) e tem até outro problema que é o *cast* implícito destes tipos, mas este é outro assunto.

A solução mais próxima que se usa e alguns até acham que pode ser mais elegante em alguns cenários é o uso de métodos de extensão ([veja que ele tem suas vantagens e desvantagens](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/121240/101)). Na resposta do Jon Skeet *linkada* acima na pergunta do autor original aqui tem a solução parecida:

```
public enum BBCodes {
    [Description("b")]
    Bold = 1,
    [Description("i")]
    Italic = 2
}

public static class BBCodesExt {
    public static string Wrap(this BBCodes code, string contents) => $"[{code.ToStringDescription()}]{contents}[/{code.ToStringDescription()}]";
    public static string ToStringDescription(this BBCodes code) {
        var attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])code.GetType().GetField(code.ToString()).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
        return attributes.Length > 0 ? attributes[0].Description : "";
    }
}
```

Dei uma melhorada para ficar no [estilo do C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/101).

Chama assim:

```
string bbcode = BBCodes.Bold.Wrap("StackOverflow");
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/7gc2Jm). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nyuCXI). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Enum/Methods.cs).

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-create-a-new-method-for-an-enumeration?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Mas se a representação *string* bater com o nome do membro em todos os casos, como foi mostrado nos 2 membros do exemplo, nem precisa disto. O `enum` tem um método [`ToString()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tostring?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Enum_ToString_System_String_) para isto.

Mas se o que deseja é a semântica de referência da classe (duvido que precise na maioria dos casos), aí é melhor simular a enumeração, mais ou menos como fez. Só procure deixar mais idiomático para C#, como mostrado e fazendo a classe ser selada (equivalente ao `final`). Ou pode fazer um pouco diferente:

```
public sealed class BBCodes {
    public static readonly string Bold = "b";
    public static readonly string Italic = "i";
    //...
    
    private string code;
    
    public BBCodes(string code) => this.code = code;
    
    public string Wrap(string contents) => $"[{code}]{contents}[/{code}]";
}
```

É possível criar uma propriedade para dar acesso de leitura/escrita do valor membro da instância, se necessário.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/zkbGJ8). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hNQQay). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Enum/Methods2.cs).

Answer (score 6):

Enumerações (`enum`) em C# aceitam alguns tipos (`byte`, `sbyte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long` ou `ulong`), mas `string` não está entre eles. Também não é possível criar métodos dentro de uma enumeração, mas ainda assim é possível chegar no resultado desejado sem muito sofrimento.

A saída é a criação de um [método de extensão](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb383977.aspx) para o tipo de enumeração desejado. A seguir irei construir uma solução com base no código da sua pergunta.

Crie a enumeração:

```
public enum BBCode
{
    [Description("b")]
    Bold,

    [Description("i")]
    Italic,

    [Description("u")]
    Underline
}
```

Na declaração da enumeração acima, decorei as constantes com o atributo [`DescriptionAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) cujo propósito é atribuir uma descrição em `string` a qualquer elemento de uma aplicação.

Crie um método de extensão para o tipo da enumeração desejada:

```
public static class MyEnumExtensions
{
    public static string Wrap(this BBCode val, string content)
    {
        var attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])val.GetType().GetField(val.ToString()).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

        if (attributes.Length <= 0)
            throw new Exception($"Not decorated with `{nameof(DescriptionAttribute)}`.");

        var code = attributes[0].Description;
        return $"[{code}]{content}[/{code}]";
    }
}
```

O método de extensão `Wrap`, definido acima, só ficará acessível para enumerações do tipo `BBCode` (daí o `this BBCode`) e sua função é obter o valor contido no atributo `DescriptionAttribute`, que foi utilizado para decorar uma constante referenciada, e retornar uma `string` formatada junto com o valor do parâmetro `content`.

Para utilizar esse método de extensão basta fazer uma simples chamada a ele em cima de uma instância da enumeração `BBCode`.

```
BBCode.Bold.Wrap("Foo"); // Retorna: "[b]Foo[/b]"
```

Note que a classe `MyEnumExtensions` precisa estar em uma namespace acessível para que o método `Wrap` possa ser chamado.

Dessa forma você tem uma comportamento muito parecido com o do código original em Java apresentado na pergunta.

Outra solução seria com a utilização de uma classe que se comportaria como uma enumeração, conforme apresentado na sua própria pergunta na sua tentativa de implementação em C#. Mas de qualquer forma você é livre para escolher a maneira que melhor lhe agrada para cada cenário, pois ambas têm suas vantagens e desvantagens.